# Windows 2003, SQL 2005 - What is server tasking and where do I find it?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005

I've been reading up on how to tune SQL Server 2005 for a machine in a test environment. I came across [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176012(v=SQL.90).aspx) on technet which suggests how to configure "server tasking" and says I should refer to the Windows 2003 docs for more info.

I have googled Windows 2003 "server tasking" (with and without the quotes) but all I can find is more similar articles on SQL server telling me that it should be configured, not how/where you do it.

I know I'm probably searching for the wrong thing - can someone please tell me how to configure it in Windows or SQL server, whichever it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever wrote that used the wrong (or an uncommon) term. It's ["processor scheduling."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737882%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: It's also called server tasking: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176012(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: But is it called that anywhere outside of the SQL documentation? I only ask because I've never heard that term until reading this question and the linked docs.

Comment: Lol - In that case I know exactly what it is! The line "When you run SQL Server Setup, server tasking is set to none in Windows Server 2003" confused me, because there is no "none" in the processor scheduling settings. I take it this is wrong?

Comment: Like you, I've never seen it referenced anywhere outside of SQL.

Comment: And they all look like different revisions of the same document. I bet the person who first wrote this SQL doc in the NT 4.0 days translated something into English incorrectly, and the term was never corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer your question directly but when I use Help and Support on one a Server 2003 machine and search for `server tasking` it locates 25 Knowledge Base articles, so I'm guessing some of those might have your answers.

The following 24 KB articles were found through Help and Support (the 25th was about Win98). I don't know how many are really relevant but I'll leave that up to you to determine.

- KB121594
- KB102061
- KB101709
- KB970821
- KB118677
- KB109228
- KB111405
- KB107245
- KB2272146
- KB103810
- KB124838
- KB101781
- KB102987
- KB140372
- KB135899
- KB293513
- KB86290
- KB90227
- KB103435
- KB72182
- KB71300
- KB85394
- KB85419
- KB96418

Comment: Unfortunately my test rig is not allowed to have any connection to the internet at present (not my rules). Is it possible you could figure out the links to a couple of these and post them?

Comment: @simon, I'll have a look in the morning (it's 11:06PM here), although by then someone else may already have answered you question.

Comment: @Simon, answer updated.

Comment: Come on man - this site can't be linkdump-and-run :-)

Comment: @mfinni, if I understood the problem (not my area) and had the time to delve deeply into those articles I would do so. As it is I'm merely trying to offer a pointer in a direction that *might* be useful. It's not like this question has been overwhelmed with better answers.